# Conditional expectation of a random function evaluated in an independent random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Let $f$ be a (deterministic) function and $W$ a Brownian motion. Let $\theta$ be a random variable that is **independent** of $W$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the natural filtration of $W$. Then I am wondering how to compute
$$\mathbb{E}[f(W_\theta)|\mathcal{F}_t],$$
where $t\geq 0$.

I imagine that the conditional expectation w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_t$ equals the conditional expectation w.r.t. $\sigma(W_t)$ by Markovianity, but I am not sure if the resulting value is a function of $W_r$ or of $\theta$. I am not sure if the operator $\mathbb{E}$ affects only $W$ (and then we evaluate $\theta$) or if it averages out "all the omegas".

Any thought on this? Thanks!

Comment: I think it is $\int E[f(W_x) | \mathcal{F}_t] d\mu(x)$ where $\mu$ is the probability law of $\theta$.

Comment: That's what I think too :) and then I guess one needs to separate between cases $x\leq t$ and $x>t$. So, $\int f(W_x)I\{x\leq t\}d\mu_\theta(x) + \int \mathbb{E}[f(W_{x-t}+z)]I\{x> t\}d\mu_\theta(x)\Bigg|_{z=W_t}$.